# Pause and resume a ReactiveKafkaReceiver based on condition

Tags: spring-kafka, resilience4j, reactive-kafka

I am trying to implement a circuit breaker with resilence4j for a kafka consumer that in turn calls a downstream API. Both the kafka consumer and API are reactive.

**Requirement**: There should be a Circuit Breaker in case the downstream API throws exception and the kafka consumer should pause if the circuit is open. The consumer should resume once the circuit goes back to closed state.

This is my consumer:

@EventListener(ApplicationStartedEvent.class)
public void consume() {

```
    reactiveKafkaReceiver
            .doOnNext(record -> {
                log.info("Reading offset {}, message:{}", record.offset(),record.value());
            })
            .concatMap(r ->
                this.processRecord(r)
                        .doOnSuccess(event -> r.receiverOffset().acknowledge())
                        .doOnError(error -> log.error("Error processing consumer events: {} ", error.getMessage()))
                        .retryWhen(Retry.backoff(3, Duration.ofSeconds(2)).transientErrors(true))
                        .onErrorResume(error -> {
                            log.error("Retries exhausted for " + r.value());
                            //deadLetterPublishingRecoverer.accept(r, new Exception(error));
                            //r.receiverOffset().acknowledge();
                            return Mono.empty();
                        }))
            .repeat()
            .subscribe();
}
```

I have been able to implement circuit breaker on the processRecord() method. Problem is, I am not able to pause and resume the kafka consumer based on circuit breaker events.

I have been able to do it in non reactive kafka using the KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry and the messageListenerContainers. I have hit a roadblock for reactive kafka. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

I tried the below but got an exception:

```
reactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate
                                    .doOnConsumer( consumer -> {
                                        // Your code inside doOnConsumer
                                        System.out.println("Consumer is ready");
                                        KafkaConsumer consumer1 = (KafkaConsumer) consumer;
                                        var partitions = (Collection<TopicPartition>)consumer1.partitionsFor("").stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
                                        consumer1.pause(partitions);
                                        //reactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate.assignment().flatMap( o -> reactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate.pause((TopicPartition)o)).subscribe();
                                        return null;
                                    }).subscribe();
```

Exception:
reactor.core.publisher.Operators","message":"Operator called default onErrorDropped","thrown":{"commonElementCount":0,"localizedMessage":"java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must call one of receive*() methods before using doOnConsumer","message":"java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must call one of receive*() methods before using doOnConsumer

**Update 2**
Tried with below as well:

```
reactiveKafkaReceiver.doOnConsumer(stringEquipmentMoveConsumer -> {
        System.out.println("Consumer is ready");
                                stringEquipmentMoveConsumer.pause(stringEquipmentMoveConsumer.assignment().stream().collect(Collectors.toList()));
                                System.out.println("Consumer is ready 1");
                                return null;
                            }).subscribe();
```

No errors, but consumer didn't stop

Answer (score 0):

I see you have that `reactiveKafkaReceiver` variable extracted. So, to perform pause on its `Consumer` you should use this API:

```
    receiver.doOnConsumer(consumer -> {
        consumer.pause(...);
        return null;
    })
```

See more info in `doOnConsumer` Javadocs:

```
/**
 * Invokes the specified function on the Kafka {@link Consumer} associated with this {@link KafkaReceiver}.
 * The function is scheduled when the returned {@link Mono} is subscribed to. The function is
 * executed on the thread used for other consumer operations to ensure that {@link Consumer}
 * is never accessed concurrently from multiple threads.
 * <p>
 * Example usage:
 * <pre>
 * {@code
 *     receiver.doOnConsumer(consumer -> consumer.partitionsFor(topic))
 *             .doOnSuccess(partitions -> System.out.println("Partitions " + partitions));
 * }
 * </pre>
 * Functions that are directly supported through the reactive {@link KafkaReceiver} interface
 * like <code>poll</code> and <code>commit</code> should not be invoked from <code>function</code>.
 * The methods supported by <code>doOnConsumer</code> are:
 * <ul>
 *   <li>{@link Consumer#assignment()}
 *   <li>{@link Consumer#subscription()}
 *   <li>{@link Consumer#seek(org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition, long)}
 *   <li>{@link Consumer#seekToBeginning(java.util.Collection)}
 *   <li>{@link Consumer#seekToEnd(java.util.Collection)}
 *   <li>{@link Consumer#position(org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition)}
 *   <li>{@link Consumer#committed(org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition)}
 *   <li>{@link Consumer#metrics()}
 *   <li>{@link Consumer#partitionsFor(String)}
 *   <li>{@link Consumer#listTopics()}
 *   <li>{@link Consumer#paused()}
 *   <li>{@link Consumer#pause(java.util.Collection)}
 *   <li>{@link Consumer#resume(java.util.Collection)}
 *   <li>{@link Consumer#offsetsForTimes(java.util.Map)}
 *   <li>{@link Consumer#beginningOffsets(java.util.Collection)}
 *   <li>{@link Consumer#endOffsets(java.util.Collection)}
 * </ul>
 *
 * @param function A function that takes Kafka {@link Consumer} as parameter
 * @return Mono that completes with the value returned by <code>function</code>
 */
<T> Mono<T> doOnConsumer(Function<Consumer<K, V>, ? extends T> function);
```

Comment: Artem, I tried but got an error. Updated my original question.

Comment: But that error said you exactly what is needed to be done. You have to use the same `KafkaReceiver` for consumption (`receive*()`) and that `doOnConsumer()`, but apparently the `receive*()` subscription must be done before you try to call `pause()`.

Comment: Tried with this but no luck. will it be possible to provide some example if you have it handy. There was no exception, the logs got printed, but the consumer didn't stop.

reactiveKafkaReceiver.doOnConsumer(stringEquipmentMoveConsumer -> {
        System.out.println("Consumer is ready");
        stringEquipmentMoveConsumer.pause(stringEquipmentMoveConsumer.assignment().stream().collect(Collectors.toList()));
                                System.out.println("Consumer is ready 1");
                                return null;
                            }).subscribe();

Comment: I don't have an example, but here is a unit test demonstrating consumption and pausing: https://github.com/reactor/reactor-kafka/blob/main/src/test/java/reactor/kafka/receiver/KafkaReceiverTest.java#L1326

Comment: Hi Artem - one more question - till what time does it pause the consumer? Is it till the next poll()? Because what is happening in my case is that the consumer is getting stopped, but is getting resumed again after sometime

Comment: Until you call `resume()`. The `poll()` is still called. That's how Kafka keeps consumer alive. To be honest, all of that has nothing to do with Reactor Kafka, since that `pause()/resume()` is native Kafka client API.

Comment: Artem - thanks for your help. I think I found the issue. The consumer is indeed getting paused - but not immediately. What is happening is that it is receiving a huge number of records and the pause is taking effect after sometime. Is there a way to control the number of records received during KafkaReceiver.create(kafkaReceiverOptions).receive()? I tried configuring the "max.poll.interval.ms" option - but it didn't help

Comment: That's correct. All the consumer operations must be performed on the same thread. Therefore if that thread is busy processing records, no way it is going to be paused immediately. I'm not sure why you talk about `max.poll.interval.ms`, but probably `max.poll.records` would be better for you